# swift xcode proper way to switch from navigation controller to tab bar controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have embedded a navigation controller like this:

[image]

I have also set this to be my root view with the arrow in storyboard pointing to this. But now I want to change so my app use a tab bar instead of a navigation controller. I have tried to click on the navigation controller than add a tab bar controller. But when I search through my storyboard xml file I still see refrences to navigation controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the *NavigationController* with a *TabBarController*:

1. Select the *NavigationController* in the Storyboard.
2. Hit the <kbd>delete</kbd> key.
3. Select your *ViewController*.
4. Select **Editor->Embed in->Tab Bar Controller** from the menu.
5. Select the *TabBarController* and check **Is Initial View Controller** in the *Attributes Inspector*.